# SVN different update and commit sources

Tags: svn

I'm going to check out a repository from a source that I can't commit changes back there. Then I'm gonna change the code and submit it to my own SVN server. The problem is that I want to keep my code also update-able from the original SVN server, but changes will always be saved to my own server.

Is it possible using externals? or they will try to commit changes back to original server?
if you know a way, is it possible to be done using tortoiseSVN?

Comment: This is a painful thing to do in SVN. If you don't have to use SVN, consider using one of the DVCs to SVN adaptors and then doing your work in Git or Mercurial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your looking for [vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s05.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think externals are for that.

You could export the source from the other repository, then import it into yours. For future updates you could merge the source from other repository into your trunk.

Answer (score 0):

As you say you dont have access to the orginal svn repostiroy its going to be pretty tricky to do it. checkout [SVK](http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/HomePage), it has this options for creating local branches and you would be able to do commit your changes into it.

As a better option you can try [git-svn](http://www.viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/), which is the better form of the above.

Comment: the problem is that repositories are already created and exist.